# With CSS only, how do I hide parent sub element if ID exists?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Using CSS only, how can i hide NAV when another element ID exists in the following element?

```
<nav>...</nav>
<div id="main">
    <div id="page-calendar">...</div>
</div>
```

I want to hide NAV when the #main element contains #page-calendar.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not do. There is no clean way to select a previous element in CSS.

[Is there a "previous sibling" selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)

---

But if you change the flow of the elements you can do. Albeit I do not **recommend** it because it is much cleaner and easier to do in javascript.

Use `nav` inside `#main` after `#page-calendar` and position it `fixed` or `aboslute` before the `#main` element. Then, you can select it using `next-sibling combinator`

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="page-calendar">Calendar</div>
    <nav>Nav</nav>
</div>
```

```css
#main {
 position: relative;
 top: 30px;
}


nav {
 position: fixed;
 top: 20px;
}

#page-calendar + nav {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="page-calendar">Calendar</div>
    <nav>Nav</nav>
</div>
```

---